# dojo fadeout working only once on function call during validation

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

On submit button action calling validation method for mandatory field validation . On clicking submit button ,  I written validation message and attached the custom message in HTML and used dojo fadeout function to provide fadeout effect. Its working perfectly fine when its calling validation method first time on submit action and fadeout working fine. Again performing submit button without providing mandatory value , its again going to validation method on submit but fadeout message not working ....

```
<tr>
<td>
    <label for="country">Country</label> <span class="required">*</span>
</td>
<td>
    <select data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ComboBox" required="true" id="country" name="country" value="">
    </select>
</td>

<td>
    <div class=alert-box-country id="alert-box-country" data-dojo-attach-point="validationNotificationCountry">
        <p data-dojo-attach-point="msgAttCountry" class="failure" id="msgCountry"></p>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>

//Function call 
if (countryServiceParams.country=="" || countryServiceParams.country==null && countryServiceParams.documentDate=="" || countryServiceParams.documentDate==null){
    alert("inside validation for Country : country");
    dojo.setStyle('alert-box-country',"display","block");
    alert('before fadeup');
    var message = 'Please provide the mandatory fields before submission';
    var messageNode= dojo.byId("msgCountry");
    messageNode.innerHTML=message;
    dojo.fadeOut({  
        node:dojo.byId("alert-box-country"), 
        duration:9000,  
    }).play();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset the `opacity`:

```
dojo.setStyle('alert-box-country',"opacity","1");
```

Comment: I tried with dojo.setStyle('alert-box-country',"opacity","1") and dojo.setStyle('alert-box-country',"opacity","0") but Its not working. message will display only once with fadeout effect . on second call its not displaying fadeout message. on refreshing page its working again for first call...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I correct it setting the the node opacity to 1.